# Flutter change CupertinoTabBar background color dynamically

Tags: flutter

I want to change background color of tab. I have 5 tabs, and I want only first tab's background to be transparent. Also active color and inactive color too.

tab bar code looks like this:

```
return new WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => new Future<bool>.value(true),
  child: new CupertinoTabScaffold(
    tabBar: new CupertinoTabBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, //change here
      activeColor: Colors.black, // here 
      inactiveColor: Colors.grey, // here too
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
          title: Text('Timeline'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
          title: Text('Talk'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: Text('Search'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          title: Text('Profile'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new DefaultTextStyle(
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',
          fontSize: 17.0,
          color: CupertinoColors.black,
        ),
        child: new CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return HomeScreen();
                break;
              case 1:
                return TimelineScreen();
                break;
              case 2:
                return TalkScreen();
                break;
              case 3:
                return SearchScreen();
                break;
              case 4:
                return ProfileScreen();
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

I tried set variable `_currentIndex` and changed depends on which index user is but I can't call `setState` because error says:

> flutter: The following assertion was thrown building _TabSwitchingView(dirty, state:
>   flutter: _TabSwitchingViewState#86c7b):
>   flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>   flutter: This HomeScreen widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
>   flutter: process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
>   flutter: only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
>   flutter: builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
>   flutter: Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.

Does anyone have an idea to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out. I'm not sure this is appropriate. 
Hope this helps.

```
 return new WillPopScope(
    int currentIndex = 0;
  onWillPop: () => new Future<bool>.value(true),
  child: new CupertinoTabScaffold(
    tabBar: new CupertinoTabBar(
     onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.white,
          activeColor: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          inactiveColor: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.grey,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
          title: Text('Timeline'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
          title: Text('Talk'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: Text('Search'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          title: Text('Profile'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new DefaultTextStyle(
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',
          fontSize: 17.0,
          color: CupertinoColors.black,
        ),
        child: new CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return HomeScreen();
                break;
              case 1:
                return TimelineScreen();
                break;
              case 2:
                return TalkScreen();
                break;
              case 3:
                return SearchScreen();
                break;
              case 4:
                return ProfileScreen();
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```